# How to replace deprecated ListView in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am studying kivy for now and reading Creating Apps with kivy. Author use follwing code:

.kv

```
AddLocationForm:

<AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>:
    orientation : 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        pos : 100, 100
        height : '40dp'
        size_hint_y : None

        TextInput:
            size_hint_x : 50
        Button:
            text : 'search'
            size_hint_x : 25
        Button:
            text : 'current location'
            size_hint_x : 25
    ListView:
        item_strings: ["Palo Alto, MX", "Palo Alto, US"]
```

and .py

```
from kivy.app import App


class FirstKivyApp(App):
    pass



FApp = FirstKivyApp()
FApp.run()
```

But as much as I understand ListView is deprecated now. It is supposed to be changed on RecycleView now. I've checked for some solutions but they don't make sense for me because use things I've not accomplished yet. I tried to use

```
RecycleView:
    data : ["Palo Alto, MX", "Palo Alto, US"]
```

instead of `ListView` but it isn't shown whereas I can access the data through `id` and `ObjectProperty`. Is there a way to display data in simplier way, than using `ScreenManager`, constructing classes and referring to `build` method? For example something like in author's or my example, but working. Adding `RecycleBoxLayout` didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

When calling your Recycleview in kivy, make sure it has an appropriate id, this can then be called in your python code with data applied with the following:

```
rows = ["Palo Alto, MX", "Palo Alto, US"]  # declare list
self.ids.rv.data = [{'text':str(row)}for row in rows]  # add list
```

The kivy docs site has a great example of how to implement RecycleView, found here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html

Try this for a basic example showing how to use ScreenManager with RecycleView:

```
import kivy
# import main libraries, import object types and layouts
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty, ObjectProperty, 
OptionProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty)
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
# import screen features
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

# load in kv file, deals with cosmetics of each screen
kv = """
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if root.selected else (0, 0, 0, .1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 
<SelectScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: .25
            height: dp(54)
            padding: dp(8)
            spacing: dp(16)
            Button:
                text: 'Select all'
                font_size: 24
                on_release:
                    controller.select_all(len(rv.data))
            Button:
                text: 'Deselect all'
                font_size: 24
                on_release:
                    controller.clear_all()  
        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
            scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
            bar_width: dp(10)
            viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                id: controller
                key_selection: 'selectable'
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True
                spacing: dp(2)
"""
Builder.load_string(kv)

# Adds selectable labels to lists (recycleview)
class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    def get_nodes(self):
        nodes = self.get_selectable_nodes()
        if self.nodes_order_reversed:
            nodes = nodes[::-1]
        if not nodes:
            return None, None

        selected = self.selected_nodes
        if not selected:  # nothing selected, select the first
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            return None, None

        if len(nodes) == 1:  # the only selectable node is selected already
            return None, None

        last = nodes.index(selected[-1])
        self.clear_selection()
        return last, nodes

    def select_all(self, num):
        print(num)
        #print(len(self.ids.rv.data))
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        print(nodes)
        for x in range(num):
            print(x)
            self.select_node(x)

    def clear_all(self):
        self.clear_selection()

# Create action on selectable list, for example apply selection remembers previous selection and saves to sqlite db
class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    index = int

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if self.selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))

# Screen for selecting from recycleview         
class SelectScreen(Screen):
    interfacename = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):   
        super(SelectScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        rows = ["Palo Alto, MX", "Palo Alto, US"]  # declare list
        self.ids.rv.data = [{'text':str(row)}for row in rows]  # add list

    def select(self): # selects participants from list new value to database
        print (self.ids.rv.data[val[0]]['text'])

    def selectall(self):
        for num in range(len(self.ids.rv.data)):
            SelectableLabel.apply_selection(self, self.ids.rv, num, True)   

# screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(SelectScreen(name='select')) # main starting menu

# Build the app return screenmanager
class RecycleviewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RecycleviewApp().run()
```

Example image of application and terminal printing application and removal of RecycleView selection:

[image]

Comment: But I don't have any place for `self` in my .py file. Should I add some method?

Comment: And do I really have to add all of this to display some list? I don't need `ScreenManager` now, I just want to display list of values in the most simple way don't changing a code tragically.

Answer (score 0):

I founded out the issue.
Firstly, format of data must be suitable. As twicejiggled showed it must be list of dicts. 
Secondly, as much as I understood, some layout is neede for showing. For example this code in .kv will work:

```
RecycleView:
    data : [{'text':'text'} for x in range(50)]
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```